# JQ - Argument list too long error - Large Input

Tags: shell, command-line-arguments, jq

I use Jq to perform some filtering on a large json file using :

```
paths=$(jq '.paths | to_entries | map(select(.value[].tags | index("Filter"))) | from_entries' input.json)
```

and write the result to a new file using :

```
jq --argjson prefix "$paths" '.paths=$prefix' input.json > output.json
```

But this ^ fails as $paths has a very high line count (order of 100,000).

Error :

```
jq: Argument list too long
```

I also went through : [/usr/bin/jq: Argument list too long error bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854249/usr-bin-jq-argument-list-too-long-error-bash) , understood the same problem there, but did not get the solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, "argument list too long" is a shell (or really OS) error when your command line contains too many bytes. The solution is often to use something else than the command line to move data between processes, or, ideally, to avoid moving all that data between processes.

Answer (score 1):

In general, assuming your jq allows it, you could use `—argfile` or `—slurpfile` but in your case you can simply avoid the issue by invoking jq just once instead of twice. For example, to keep things clear:

```
 ( .paths | to_entries | map(select(.value[].tags | index("Filter"))) | from_entries ) as $prefix
 | .paths=$prefix
```

Even better, simply use `|=`:

```
 .paths |= ( to_entries | map(select(.value[].tags | index("Filter"))) | from_entries)
```

or better yet, use `with_entries`.

Comment: I will try out the above, post exact working command and accept this answer, thanks.