# -bash: /bin/jq: Argument list too long

Tags: command-line-arguments, jq

Below 2 jq statements read large json file and copy to another json file. but this statement throws "Argument too long" error. This perfectly fine for smaller json files.

```
$ apiDefinitionString=`jq -r '. | tojson' api.json`
$ jq --arg definition "$apiDefinitionString" '.apiDefinition = $definition' api-new.json > api-spec.json
```

I tried to replace --arg with ----slurpfile as well as recommended in another thread[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854249/usr-bin-jq-argument-list-too-long-error-bash) and its same error.

Do I any other option to solve this Jq issue ? Is this Jq limitation ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Simply replacing --arg with --slurpfile has no chance of working.  Please follow the [mcve] guidelines more closely.  What is the value of $apiDefinitionString? What exactly did you try when using --slurpfile?  Have you read the jq manual's explanation of --slurpfile?

Comment: @peak I have same error if output var size is 204800 or more.
What I am doing that I am creating a var (output) of various sizes and then inserting it into a json object like this 
# Creating a var with required size here 200Kb
output=$(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c 204800)
# Adding a new key:val in already existing json file
jq --arg v "$output" '.[] += {"Random Data": $v}'  sample.json > new_file.json

-bash: /bin/jq: Argument list too long

Any suggestion how to fix this when I am using variable of various sizes?

Comment: @PrashantPathak - Have you tried the approach given in my A to this Q?

Comment: @peak In your answer I see a file is getting read into a variable and then the variable is passed as one of the filed in json file under apiDefinition array and redirecting it to a file. In my case I am creating a variable and assigning it random size string from stdout stream and then trying to insert the var into a json key:val. Was not able to execute the suggestion you have given in my scenario.

Comment: @PrashantPathak - Perhaps you misunderstand the example. You might want to use `sponge`.

Answer (score 1):

The --slurpfile option is very different from the --arg option.  For one thing, it expects a file (or file handle) to be provided; also, it wraps the contents of the file into an array.

Even though the --argfile option is deprecated, I would suggest you begin by trying to use it in the simplest possible way, e.g. by first writing the contents of your shell variable to a file, perhaps along the lines of:

```
jq -r 'tojson' api.json > out.tmp
jq --argfile definition out.tmp '.apiDefinition = $definition' api-new.json > api-spec.json
```

When you've got that working, you can move onto better variations.

Better yet, you should be able to combine the two calls to jq into one:

```
jq --argfile definition api.json '.apiDefinition = ($definition|tojson)' api-new.json > api-spec.json
```

Comment: With bash (but not a POSIX shell), you can avoid the temp file in the first snippet using`<( )`: `jq --argfile definition <( jq -r 'tojson' api.json ) ...`

Answer (score 0):

> `Argument list too long is a system error`. Argument and environment
> sizes are limited by all Unix-like kernels. You exceeded that size.
> Use -f to pass extra large programs. (But beware that jq function
> bodies, and the top-level jq program, are limited in compiled size to
> 64K code units each.)

Comment: This quotation is mostly irrelevant as $apiDefinitionString is evidently not a jq program.